# Icons on some beta sites' chat not showing up correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design

Probably related to the recent 3D-takeover, on Vi and Vim chat, the feeds' icons aren't showing up:

[image]

And the Vi and Vim logo on the bottom bar:

[image]

And for elementaryOS:

[image]

And on German Language:

[image]

Comment: [My answer on the 3D post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277525/270345) was deleted without comment, so perhaps it's a different issue.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker tried Ctrl-F5 (which, IIRC, ignores cache), tried incognito mode, switched to Firefox... The bottom bar logo has started showing up, the feed icons are still missing.

Comment: And I think it's weird the icon is called [apple-touch-icon.png](http://sstatic.net/vi/img/apple-touch-icon.png).

Comment: Do you have a link to a room? That'll help us out a lot.

Comment: @NickCraver http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20803/chat for [vi.se], http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/deutschsprachiger-raum for [german.se]. Yes, the site logos have started showing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feeds in chat have now been updated - thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks! So it was unrelated to the 3D issue?

Comment: The move of all static content was the same root cause, but totally different item/codebase affected - yes.